# i am try to get the access_token inside the layout.js using getAccessTokenWithPop() but it not providing any token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, access-token, auth0

**main.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain="dev-fpc4abpe4idt658a.us.auth0.com"
      clientId="9dJ0MOrpMbIOIqV7NqSda3X8PusCyrWm"
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5173",
      }}
      audience="http://localhost:8000"
      scope="openid profile email"
    >
      <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import UserDetailContext from "../../context/UserDetailContext";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";
import { createUser } from "../../utils/api";

const Layout = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, user, getAccessTokenWithPopup } = useAuth0();
  const { setUserDetails } = useContext(UserDetailContext);

  const { mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationKey: [user?.email],
    mutationFn: () => createUser(user?.email),
  });

   useEffect(() => {
    const getTokenAndRegsiter = async () => {
      console.log("trying to get the token")
      const res = await getAccessTokenWithPopup({
        authorizationParams: {
          audience: "http://localhost:8000",
          scope: "openid profile email",
        },
      });
      console.log("token is : ",res);
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", res);
      setUserDetails((prev) => ({ ...prev, token: res }));
      mutate(res)
    };


    isAuthenticated && getTokenAndRegsiter();
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ background: "var(--black)", overflow: "hidden" }}>
        <Header />
        <Outlet />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Frontend is working fine but I am getting an error showing Error: Service not found: http://localhost:8000

I am not getting What is wrong. I have attached the code above.
I am new to development, somebody pleasee help!!

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Service not found: http://localhost:8000 at new OAuthError2 (errors.tsx:9:11)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are duplicating the project at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rN1fNO-ATb0 (**React Full Stack Responsive Real Estate website Tutorial - React Projects for Beginners, Deploy**), this is an issue not mentioned in the video.

The solution is to create the API on auth0.com. The identifier should be "http://localhost:8000". See the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an identifier for your backend API. To create that,

1. Go to your auth0 site where you created your application.
2. There in navigations, go to "APIs" tab.
3. Create your custom API.
4. Then go to its settings and set your "identifier" as your backend audience url.
5. Click save and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an identifier for your backend API. To do that,

Go to your auth0 site where you created your application.
There in navigations, go to "APIs" tab.
Create your custom API.
Then go to its settings and set your "identifier" as your backend audience url.
Click save, then coppy the identifier and use it as your audience.

Answer (score 0):

change the audience from localhost:8000 to the identifier issued by auth0 on the APis. This value will be used as the audience parameter on authorization calls.